# Popular answer saying that helping the library hurts many tears (a Japanese poem)

Tags: discussion, support, specific-answer

I've found [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library) with a [strange popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233765/1476885).

[image: answer with japanese text]

The first part of the answer is just fine, but it finishes with some Japanese text:

> 図書館 助け
>   足場が痛い
>   多くの涙

I don't know what it means. Google translator tells me the following (hence the title of my question):

[image: Help the library Scaffolding hurts Many tears]

Since the answer was locked, I've raised a moderator flag to remove this distracting Japanese text and it was declined with the following reasoning:

> It is a haiku. It can stay in the post just fine.

So, a [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) is a Japanese poem, but I couldn't find its meaning and why it is related to this answer.

<sup>I thought of asking about this in JAP.SE, but they are [not a translation service](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info).</sup>

### My questions are:

1. What is the background of this popular answer? [support](/questions/tagged/support) (It is locked because it generated a great amount of comments).
2. Shouldn't this answer be unlocked and the Japanese text removed? [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (or at least edited to explain the poem)

Comment: Terrible poem if that's what it translates to ;) In all honesty I agree it should at least be explained because it's on an English site and adds zero value. It's ironic that the post has been locked _due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated_.

Comment: Yeah and there's not even a huge amount of comments, @Bugs. Just over a dozen of them. I don't know why the post was locked, considering there had been only *one* comment left on the answer in nearly a *year* before the answer was locked. But I'm not touching it.

Comment: @BoltClock it seems possible that moderator who applied the lock intended to use "content dispute" but fat fingered and picked other kind of lock

Comment: There's also an answer saying *a framework is a way of life*... Some deep stuff going on with that Q.

Comment: Huh... I can't remember why I would have locked that post. It doesn't seem to have been necessary, as noted above. I was responding to a flag on the post, but the flag wasn't requesting a lock. Maybe I got confused and thought all of the comments were recent, but that still wouldn't warrant a multi-year lock.

Comment: I've unlocked the post. Looking at the timestamps, it was only a few days after I was elected as a moderator, so I may have still been confused by the new interface, or not realized that I was locking it indefinitely. FWIW, the question is already closed as off topic and I'd prefer to leave the haiku in the answer -- it's relatively harmless flair that makes the point a bit more memorable -- but will defer to the community and active moderators on that.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, thanks, but do you know its translation? Editing the answer to link to a translation or explanation of the poem would improve the post. As it currently stands, it is just strange.

Comment: @Zanon: Try asking on [japanese.se].

Comment: @jwodder `I thought of asking about this in JAP.SE, but they are not a translation service.` (taken from the question)

Comment: A site for QA. Someones brings poetry. We hate fun.

Comment: Scaffolding appears to be a mistranslation of Framework. The rest is really... garbled? I'd bet this started as an English haiku, got Google-Translated to Japanese, and pasted into the answer.

Comment: I vote to remove the haiku, but I'll leave the execution to someone else.

Comment: "The first part of the answer is just fine" - is it? I mean, I guess it got some upvotes for amusing brevity, but it's not even good English, let alone a good answer to the question.

Comment: Golly you guys went on safari. Part of the reason it doesn't make sense nine years later is that all the comments that provided context are gone. Suffice it to say: it was best attempt at 5-7-5 translation of the answer. I do remember it wasn't exact. I don't what the exact wording was.

Comment: It's useless noise, and it's not even in English. If the answer as a whole had anything of value, I'd say the poem should be edited out. Sadly, the question itself is off-topic and primarily opinion-based. It should either get a historical lock (if it's absolutely vital that we keep it for some reason) or (ideally) be deleted entirely.

Comment: @carla: I saw what you did there! :-)

Comment: I have a framework; I have a pain. うん！framework pain!

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the problem there. It's part of this time when questions like that were authorized, and fun was a bit more tolerated. If this should dissapear, I think a lot of other answers should be edited/deleted too. I would just keep it in its current state, and let it live in the SO past. After all, it doesn't harm anyone.

Comment: *JAP.SE* [triggered]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what about this answer bothers you. No cuddly kittens are being harmed.

But let me point out that this is not a haiku. Haiku is 5-7-5. This is 7-7-7. There is no form of [Japanese poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_poetry) with such a meter.

More basically, it is not even remotely intelligible Japanese. The word for "library" has been translated as 図書館 (*toshokan*) which refers to a building containing books; a programming library would be ライブラリ. The author is apparently using 足場 (*ashiba*, loosely, "foothold", or also "foundation" or "scaffolding") to mean "framework", but again, this would be フレームワーク in Japanese. The intent seems to be to say

> Help, O library;
>   My framework is so painful.
>   Overflowing tears.

(which by the way is a "true" haiku, being 5-7-5), but the version in the post is a horrible, horrible translation of that. If there's any reason to downvote/delete this answer, it would be just that it is such a horrible mangling of Japanese.

Comment: Maybe the second line could be roughly translated `frameworks are painful`(?)

Comment: It's been about 9 years since the answer was posted, Google's algorithm has doubtless changed. I bet this "poem" read a lot differently back when it was first pasted into the translator. (Or I don't know, maybe Babel Fish? Was that still prominent in 2008?)

Comment: There needs to be a word like "Engrish" for English, for every language.

Comment: @BoltClock Japainful?

Comment: "Let me first point out that this is not a haiku." – Okay, but the *entire argument* for rejecting the OP's flag was "This is a haiku". Since it is *not*, that means that it should be removed, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is clear now that this is not a popular poem nor it has a relevant history. It seems to be just a poor use of a translation software.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean it this way but when I read "I'm not quite sure what your problem is" it comes off sounding a bit condescending

Comment: Mangled Japanese bothers torazaburo. Kittens are unharmed.

Comment: You seem to know Japanese well. Maybe it would be preferable if you made an edit on the answer fixing the poem, instead of downvoting it?

Comment: Art can not be fixed. It will stay as it is, fake. Edits are futile.

Comment: @artem, surely "Art can not be fixed/Edits are futile/It will stay as it is." Or is this a meta-joke?

Comment: @KenY-N I mean if you fix it, it becomes fake because it's not the original anymore. And on some level, all art is fake.

Comment: `'I'm not quite sure what about this answer bothers you'`. People here are adamant about removing 'Thanks' from questions, but you're not sure why a poem, in a foreign language - completely unrelated to answering the question - is being discussed? It's fluff. It should be removed.

Comment: You say that like everyone adds Japanese poetry to every other post, @Rob.

Comment: @BoltClock this particular fluff may be uncommon, but fluff in general is not. All fluff should be removed regardless of whether or not it's 'common'.

Comment: @Rob: Mysticial's branch prediction answer might need a bit of pruning, then.

Comment: @BoltClock unlikely so. One doesn't need to know Japanese to understand the "scaffolding" in branch prediction answer and see how it helps to understand the explanation As opposed to answer discussed here

Comment: @BoltClock which part of Mystical's answer does not answer the question?

Comment: @Braiam: None, but the railroad junction analogy doesn't really need to be there. It's a cute illustration of branch prediction, but ultimately fluff, much like the poem in the answer being discussed here (which is an equally cute albeit horrendously executed attempt at decorating the answer).

Comment: A little note: "足場" commonly used to tell "scaffolding" or temporary structures in sense of building/skyscraper construction. "Scaffolding" in programming context more often using "スキャフォールディング", which carries meaning derived from "足場".

Comment: @BoltClock I disagree that analogies are not part of an answer which is explaining functionality. The poem does not contribute to the answer *whatsoever*. The analogy does. It's not fluff; it's an *aid for explaining the functionality.* The zargo text post is a better example of fluff staying on the site.

Comment: I'll be the [odd one out](http://static.fjcdn.com/gifs/Having+an+unpopular+opinion+on+fj_9a6581_4717856.gif) and propose: edit the answer but just to correctly translate the haiku. Better yet! Let's make a contest for people to submit a **proper haiku** that delivers the same(ish) message.

Comment: Another note: Constant 7 moras per row means that "poem" seems much like "iroha" rather than "haiku" ("iroha" begins with i-ro-ha-ni-ho-he-to, total 7 moras). However, "iroha" allows only one per each kana character used in entire length, hence the "poem" is neither "haiku" nor "iroha".

Answer (score 18):

Answering my own question:

#### 1. What is the background of this popular answer?

Just an old answer trying to be fun in a time where fun was allowed. There is no special meaning and it is not a real poem. According to [torazaburo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345457/1476885), it is a horrible mangling of Japanese that could be translated as:

> Help, O library;
>   My framework is so painful.
>   Overflowing tears.

This text was probably created using a translation software. A ♦ moderator undeleted [two comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library/233765#comment34266130_233765) that shows an user asking for the OP to create a haiku (poem) with the previous text.

Regarding the answer lock, [Jeremy Banks ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345434/popular-answer-saying-that-helping-the-library-hurts-many-tears-a-japanese-poem?noredirect=1#comment456704_345434) said that it was probably locked by accident.

#### 2. Shouldn't this answer be unlocked and the Japanese text removed?

[Jeremy Banks ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345434/popular-answer-saying-that-helping-the-library-hurts-many-tears-a-japanese-poem?noredirect=1#comment456704_345434) has unlocked the answer and it could be edited out. However, maybe it could be kept as is since now there is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library/233765#comment72735362_233765) that explains the joke for curious people (like me).

Comment: Although I believe the Japanese text _should_ be removed, or at the very least explained, I do hope that the author provides a solid translation. I'm not sure _my framework is painful_ or _scaffolding hurts_ are quite what was intended.

Comment: Instead of *my framework is painful*, maybe *Frameworks are painful*?  I don't know Japanese, but that would make more sense in English.

Comment: The background is that back then fun was still welcome ;)

Comment: Not a *well-composed* poem, sure. Not in a traditional form, either (not that that's particularly relevant). But "not a poem" isn't warranted.

Comment: I think more proper translation becomes this: "Library helps, framework hurts, tears overflowing" - much like he (answerer) prefers library than framework. However, he wrongly uses "scaffolding" in place of "framework", by examining question context.

Comment: @Gimby I don't see what's fun about a poem that is irrelevant to the question, the answer, is unintelligible in either language, and isn't even a good poem. It's not like someone put a good poem in an answer that was meaningful and relevant to the answer. That would be fun.

Comment: @DavidConrad 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves Did gyre and gimbal in the wabe; all mimsy were the borogroves, And the mome raths outgrabe.

Comment: @matt That's quite a fun poem and I've known it (and the rest of it) by heart for over forty years now, but it's only appropriate in an answer if it has *something to do* with that answer.

Comment: @DavidConrad and there the reason for why we shall have no fun - its too personal. I saw a comment asking for a haiku which was met beyond the call of duty and cracked a smile in hindsight. Moving along.